# How to take the return values from the two calls to Multiply, add those together, and print the results?

Tags: c#

In your Main method, take the return values from the two calls to Multiply, add those together, and print the result. Multiply(2.5, 2) should return 5, and Multiply(6, 7) should return 42, so you should get a result of 47.

Using C# I have written the following code however I only get the answer of 42 and get errors when I try to add them. Any ideas on how I can add the two calls to get 47 instead of 42. [This](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/c-basics-2/methods/return-values-2) is a link to the challenge on Treehouse:

```
using System;

class Program
{    
    static double Multiply(double firstParam, double secondParam)
    {
        return (firstParam * secondParam);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Multiply(2.5, 2);
        Multiply(6, 7);
    }    
}
```

The output should be 47.

Comment: (Devils advocate) Where in your code do you capture the results of the calls to Multiply? This is homework so do try and work through it yourself. Of course at some point someone will come along and just give you the answer, but do resist the temptation to straight out use it as working it out is more important a  learning process

Comment: Write the algorithm out in //comments first, then put the c# necessary to implement the comment, underneath it

Answer (score 0):

`Multiply` returns a `double` so you can just add the results together:

```
var total = Multiply(2.5, 2) + Multiply(6, 7);
Console.WriteLine($"result: {total}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply should only be responsible for multiplying numbers, if you try to return result of summation of multiplied values it's a sign of **Single Responsibilty** violation. So you can do one of the followings:

```
double value1 = Multiply(2.5, 2);
double value2 = Multiply(6, 7);

double total = value1 + value2; // which is equal to 47 in your case
```

Or pass results of multiplied values to a sum method as below:

```
static double Sum(double d1, double d2)
{
    return d1 + d2;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var total = Sum(value1, value2);
```

Or you can simple do it like this:

```
var total =  Multiply(2.5, 2) + Multiply(6, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do it but you can capture the results the Multiply

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {

    public static double result = 0;

    static double Multiply(double firstParam, double secondParam)
    {
        return result += firstParam * secondParam;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Multiply(2.5, 2);
        Multiply(6, 7);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
}
```